# Setting up OpenVZ container private area

Tags: lvm, openvz, volume, container

I would like to install two `OpenVZ` templates, each one in a different logical volume. I have created a separate partition, made it a physical volume, assigned it a group volume and separated in two logical volumes `vzprimary` and `vzsecondary`, mounted on `/vz/vzprimary` and `/vz/vzsecondary` like this:

```
[root@primary lost+found]# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_box0-lv_root
                       18G  3.7G   13G  23% /
tmpfs                 946M  224K  946M   1% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             477M   65M  387M  15% /boot
/dev/mapper/lvm-vzprimary
                      4.7G  9.7M  4.4G   1% /vz/primary
/dev/mapper/lvm-vzsecondary
                      4.7G  9.7M  4.4G   1% /vz/secondary
```

I would like to install one template in eache logical volume. Can I do that? From what I read, I could not find an option like that: the `vzctl create` command requires only the CT ID and the name of the OS template as arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have `--private` option for `vzctl create`:

```
vzctl create CTID --private /vz/primary
vzctl create CTID --private /vz/secondary
```

If each container has a dedicated partition, also consider specifying `--layout simfs`.  ploop might be unneeded overhead.